# SQL запрос на выборку из трёх таблиц

Tags: sql

Мне нужно сформировать SQL-запрос на выборку из трёх связанных таблиц. Я написал запрос. Но при его выполнении поля, которые я указываю в части `SELECT`, воспринимаются как параметры и мне их предлагается ввести, что мне вовсе не нужно. Подскажите, где ошибка.

```
SELECT Студенты.Фамилия, Дисциплины.Аббревиатура, Пропуски.Дата 
FROM Студенты stud, Дисциплины disp, Пропуски prop 
WHERE stud.ID_студента=prop.ID_студента 
    AND disp.ID_дисциплины=prop.ID_дисциплины 
    AND prop.Дата BETWEEN #" & Me.From.Value & "# AND #" & Me.Till.Value & "#;
```

P.S. `Me.From`/`Till.Value` - это поля формы, в которой нужно обработать запрос
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    s.Фамилия,
    d.Аббревиатура,
    p.Дата
from студенты s
inner join Пропуски p
    on s.id_студента=p.id_студента
    and p.Дата beetwen #" & Me.From.Value & "# AND #" & Me.Till.Value & "#
inner join Дисциплины d
    on p.id_дисциплины=d.id_дисциплины
```

как то так. а вообще зачем связь английского с русским? ну в крайнем случае латиницей называли бы поля

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Тут ещё одна проблема выскочила: при выбор даты в поле формы дата записывается в формате "дд.мм.гг", что в принципе правильно. Но запрос не срабатывает. Когда открываешь созданный запрос в режиме конструктора, то в поле "Условие отбора" дата стоит уже в формате "дд:мм:гг". Почему так происходит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: приводить дату к одному формату. возникло подозрение по поводу правильности структуры таблицы. я надеюсь Вы дату храните как datetime?!

Comment: Да, всё верно. Но почему оно переделывает форматы, непонятно.

Comment: маловато информации для других подсказок, что за форма где Вы вводите условия для отбора?какой конструктор.Вы случайно не на 1С пишете?

Comment: Кароч. Тут всё просто. Работаю под Access на VBA. Есть форма, на которой есть textbox формата "Короткий формат даты". И есть кнопка "показать", по нажатию которой должен высветиться результат вышеизложенного запроса из трёх таблиц. То есть запрос должен высветить всех студентов, кто в эту дату пропустил занятия. Но дата, выбранная в поле формы, используется совершенно в другом формате. Пробовал с помощью DAO проверить работу с датой и написал rst.FindFirst "Дата= #" & Me.From.Value & "#", но запись не находит, а активной становится только 1-я запись.

Comment: @Кирилл тут я Вам помочь не смогу, с аксесом плотно не работал.но больше чем уверен что проблема в приведении типов к одному формату

Answer (score 0):

Вы указываете алиас для таблиц, а в SELECT их не используете:

```
SELECT stud.Фамилия, disp.Аббревиатура, prop.Дата FROM
Студенты stud, Дисциплины disp, Пропуски prop WHERE
stud.ID_студента=prop.ID_студента AND disp.ID_дисциплины=prop.ID_дисциплины 
AND prop.Дата BETWEEN #" & Me.From.Value & "# AND #" & Me.Till.Value & "#;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Полезное замечание)